# Regular expressions in listings

Tags: listings, color, syntax, sourcecode

I'm looking for a possibility to use regular expression in listings. I'd like to highlight each N thats followed by 4 decimal numbers for example N1234. How can I achieve that?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstdefinelanguage{NCSyntax}
{morekeywords={N\d\d\d\d},  % <-- regular expression ???
sensitive=false,
morecomment=[l]{;},
morestring=[b]",
}

\lstnewenvironment{mylang}{\lstset{language=NCSyntax, keywordstyle=\color{red}\bfseries\underbar }}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{mylang}
N1234   ; colored as keyword
A1234   ; text
N12     ; text
N12345  ; text
N4242   ; colored as keyword                
\end{mylang}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). I assume by "decimal numbers" you mean "digits 0 thru 9".

Comment: yes I mean digits 0-9

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for a package.


Comment: Supporting regexs would be a very big feature request for `listings` (or indeed most TeX packages), and so is really outside of our scope.

Comment: @JosephWright If this question should be closed, it should be as "too broad" rather than as "off topic".

Comment: @Jubobs In general, feature requests have been regarded as off-topic (not answerable in a Q&A format): the broadness or otherwise of the request isn't the key here.

Comment: @JosephWright Ok, fair enough. I recently tidied up many unanswered questions about [tag:listings]; maybe I was a bit overzealous on that one.