# TeXstudio: change color of errors / warnings

Tags: texstudio

I want to change the text-color of the messages given in error-Tab.

In fact the yellow / orange of the warnings is quite bad to read.

In the options-dialog I only found possibilities to change the colors of syntax-highlighting.

Anyone knows, how to archive this?

Comment: Do you want to change the text colour appearing in the panel below the code? Here the errors are in red font.

Comment: Changing the color is currently not possible for the user.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for a TeX IDE.

Comment: @Jubobs: I do not think that this is so clear, because TeX IDEs and using TeX via IDEs are on-topic.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I guess there is a debate over this type of *close*. See [Joseph's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107670/regular-expressions-in-listings#comment352957_107670).

Comment: @Jubobs: The question is not a feature request in the first place. It is a question about the configuration of a TeX IDE. Someone could write an answer that this issue cannot be configured (up to the current version x.y) and that a feature request is or should be made. Then the question can vanish from the unanswered question list.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I now understand you and I agree with you.